# Pass custom variables to onResourceRequested with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, automated-tests, build-automation, headless

In order to avoid regressions with our analytics tagging, I want to use PhantomJS to automate testing for Adobe Analytics tags.

To do so I want to be able to test 2 things:

- Presence of certain js variables declarations in the HTML source
- Compare the variables in HTML source with Ajax calls made to Adobe Analytics and ensure they have the same values

Exemple of variable in the HTML source I want to *spy* on:

```
<script>s.events="event27";</script>
```

Here is the js test script I have so far:

```
"use strict";

if (!String.prototype.contains) {
    String.prototype.contains = function (arg) {
        return !!~this.indexOf(arg);
    };
}

var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onResourceRequested = function(request) {
    var obj = JSON.stringify(request, undefined, 4);

    var needle = '2o7';
    var url = request.url;

    if (url.contains(needle)) {
        var calledUrl = decodeURI(decodeURIComponent(url));
        console.log(calledUrl);
    }
};

page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
    var jsonResponse = JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 4);
};

page.open('http://www.domain.com/page.html', function() {
    var s_account = page.evaluate(function () {
        return window.s_account;
    });

    var s_events = page.evaluate(function () {
        return window.s.events;
    });

    phantom.exit();
});
```

I would like to be able to **pass s_account and s_events variables to the onResourceRequested function** so that I can assert equality between these 2 variables and _GET params in calledUrl var.

But I can not figure out how to do so. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

I found the way to do it.

I actually get the content of window.s_account from within the onResourceRequested callback:

```
page.onResourceRequested = function(request) {
    var obj = JSON.stringify(request, undefined, 4);

    var needle = '2o7';
    var url = request.url;

    var result = false;


    if (url.contains(needle)) {
        var s_account = page.evaluate(function () {
            return window.s_account;
        });

        result = true;
        var calledUrl = decodeURI(decodeURIComponent(url));

        console.log(s_account);
    }
};
```

It might not be the most elegant way to do it however but it works.